# Proof that a set is closed, having compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

> **8.** Let $G$ be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R$.  Let $x_0\in G$ and put $F=[x_0,\infty) \cap G^c$.  Here $[x_0,\infty) = \{x\in \mathbb R : x\ge x_0 \}$.
> (a) Prove that $F$ is a non-empty set.
> (b) Prove that $F$ is a closed set.

I already solved all parts except for part b).
Can please someone help me proving part b?

This is how I solved it:

Set F is the intersection of two closed sets: $[x_0,∞)$ and $G^c$ so it is closed. However if $[x_0,∞)⊂G$ then $F=∅$ so it cannot be shown that F is non-empty. Let us say that $[x_0,∞)⊂G$ is not true. Then some $y$ exists with $y≥x_0$ and $y ∈ G^c$. Then $y∈F$ so $F$ is not empty. In that case we have:
for every $x∈F$ it is true that $x≥x_0$.
some $ε>0$ exists such that $(x_0−ε,x_0+ε)⊂G$ (because $G$ is open and $x_0∈G$). This implies that $F⊂[x_0+ε,∞)$ so $inf F≥x_0+ε>x_0$.
let us denote $inf F$ by $b$. If $b∈G$ then $(b−ε,b+ε)⊂G$ for some $ε>0$. Then $(b−ε,b+ε)∩F=∅$ contradicting that $b=inf F$. Let $y∈[x_0,b)$. If $y∉G$ then $y∈F$. But $y<b$ so this contradicts that $b=inf F$.

Comment: We do not know what definition of "closed" you are working with (there are multiple equivalent definitions). You should specify this. You should also include your thoughts/previous efforts in trying to solve the question.

Comment: check the edit, I showed my attempts.._.-

Comment: How about the definition of closed? Also, try to use MathJax to format your math. It will make it easier for people to read and increase the likelihood of a response to your question. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: We have to prove that F is a closed set. We have F is equal to the intersection of two sets. If I can prove that these two sets are closed, then F would also be closed..

Comment: What is Ac ? You did not define it.

Comment: @parsiad check the edit

Comment: @babemcnuggets check the edit please

Comment: I still think you should define closed. Defining closed as "the intersection of two closed sets" is a circular definition.

Answer (score 2):

$F$ is indeed the intersection of two closed sets:  $G^c$ is closed  as $G$ is open.   Also, $[x_0,\infty)$ is closed because it is the complement of $(-\infty,x_0)$, which is open.

$\therefore F$ is closed.

Comment: yes, this is how i was going to prove this. But how can I prove that [x0,∞)  is closed  starting with that its complement is open? I mean how can I prove that his complemennt is open?

Comment: Any $x\in (-\infty,x_0)$ has a nbhd contained in $(-\infty, x_0)$.  Just take the interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) $, where $\epsilon =\frac12\mid x-x_0\mid$.

Comment: How is this going to help me to prove that the complement of [x0,∞) is open? Thank you for clarifying

Comment: A set is open iff every point has a nbhd contained in it.

Comment: okay thank you so much